# Convert Elastic Search Query to Elastica

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elastica

I have an Elastic Search query as:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [ 
       {
       "match": {"title": "accountant"}
       },
       {
          "nested": {
            "path": "schools", 
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [ 
                  { "match": { "schools.school_name": "Duke University" }}
                ]
        }}}}
      ]
}}}
```

I'm using Elastica library of php and I want to convert this raw query into Elastica. I know I can run raw query from Elastica, but I would prefer using Elastica classes. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27665866/fos-elastica-nested-filter-not-working) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24383322/how-to-perform-nested-queries-with-elastica-search-and-symfony2). But none of them works. Here is the simplified version of my current code:

```
$schoolsTermFilter = new \Elastica\Filter\Term(['schools.school_name' => "Duke University"]);
$schoolsBoolFilter = new \Elastica\Filter\Bool();
$schoolsBoolFilter->addMust($schoolsTermFilter);

$nestedFilter = new \Elastica\Filter\Nested();
$nestedFilter->setPath("schools");
$nestedFilter->setFilter($schoolsBoolFilter);

$boolFilter = new \Elastica\Filter\Bool();
$boolFilter->addMust($nestedFilter);

$query->setPostFilter($boolFilter);
```

However, this returns empty results. The raw query does return results, so I know I should get something. Can anybody help me in this? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a 1:1 translation to Elastica for your query:

```
$query = new \Elastica\Query();

$matchQuery = new \Elastica\Query\Match();
$matchQuery->setField("title", "accountant");

$schoolsTermQuery = new \Elastica\Query\Match();
$schoolsTermQuery->setField("schools.school_name", "Duke University");
$schoolsBoolQuery = new \Elastica\Query\Bool();
$schoolsBoolQuery->addMust($schoolsTermQuery);

$nestedQuery = new \Elastica\Query\Nested();
$nestedQuery->setPath("schools");
$nestedQuery->setQuery($schoolsBoolQuery);

$boolQuery = new \Elastica\Query\Bool();
$boolQuery->addMust($matchQuery);
$boolQuery->addMust($nestedQuery);

$query->setQuery($boolQuery);

print_r(json_encode($query->toArray()));
```

The Elasticsearch query which you have pasted does not contain filters, only queries. So, the Elastica translation should not use objects from `\Elastica\Filter` but from `\Elastica\Query` instead. Also, if you want to verify the query before using it in Elasticsearch, you can print it with `$query->toArray()`.

Answer (score 6):

This is the QueryBuilder version (>= v1.4.2.0):

```
$qb = new \Elastica\QueryBuilder();

$query = new \Elastica\Query(
    $qb->query()->bool()
        ->addMust($qb->query()->match(
            'title',
            'accountant'
        ))
        ->addMust($qb->query()->nested()
            ->setPath('schools')
            ->setQuery(
                $qb->query()->bool()
                    ->addMust($qb->query()->match(
                        'schools.school_name',
                        'Duke University'
                    ))
            )
        )
);
```